# How to get Squarespace page with custom CSS to display properly on mobile?

Tags: html, css, squarespace

I've been making this website for a friend and pretty much have it done and ready to go except that the page does not display properly on mobile. The issues I'm having have more to do with how to implement CSS with these Squarespace templates than how to use mobile styles. Right now I'm attempting to get the mobile specific CSS to display on mobile pages but it is not displaying how I want. The Navbar should be underneath the logo and the logo itself in a proper size on the top of the page.This is my CSS:

```
footer {
    display:none  
}

#collection-5de6d28545f1a7075b7a2741 #canvas{
  max-width: 100% !important;
 padding-left: 0px !important;
 padding-right: 0px !important;
 padding-top: 11px !important;
 background: url(https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5cff45ae4a957c0001a6673b/t/5dc6fcead1c0ab7b9e4f5e60/1573321963518/richie_+5.jpeg)no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

#collection-5de6d2e045f1a7075b7a34a3 #canvas{
  background-position: cover;
  max-width: 100% !important;
 padding-left: 0px !important;
 padding-right: 0px !important;
 padding-top: 11px !important;
  background: url(https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5cff45ae4a957c0001a6673b/t/5df035e05d133c6a73380fa1/1576023521067/IMG_1683.JPG)
}

#collection-5de6d306623e3a140935efd4{
  max-width: 100% !important;
 padding-left: 0px !important;
 padding-right: 0px !important;
 padding-top: 11px !important;
  background-position: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

#collection-5de6d306623e3a140935efd4 #canvas {
  background-position: cover;
  max-width: 100% !important;
 padding-left: 0px !important;
 padding-right: 0px !important;
 padding-top: 11px !important;
   background: url(https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5cff45ae4a957c0001a6673b/t/5e13d4a0718bc301c1c7efcd/1578357920526/512679.jpg)
}

#collection-5de7d7f5cb49636dc8f582f0 #canvas{
  background-position: cover;
  max-width: 100% !important;
 padding-left: 0px !important;
 padding-right: 0px !important;
 padding-top: 11px !important;
   background: url(https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5cff45ae4a957c0001a6673b/t/5e13d4a0718bc301c1c7efcd/1578357920526/512679.jpg)
}

#collection-5de7f3679b018c732a115e55 #canvas {
  background-position: cover;
  max-width: 100% !important;
 padding-left: 0px !important;
 padding-right: 0px !important;
 padding-top: 11px !important;
   background: url(https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5cff45ae4a957c0001a6673b/t/5e13d4a0718bc301c1c7efcd/1578357920526/512679.jpg)
}

.page-divider {
  display: none
}

 .logo-image .logo img{
   max-height: 200px;
   max-width: 400px;
   position: relative;
   right: -50px;
   top: -50px 
 }

.info-footer-wrapper {
  display: none
}

@media screen and (max-width: 641px) {
body {font-size: __ }
h1 {font-size: __ }
h2 {font-size: __ }
h3 {font-size: __ }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  #header {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }}
```

I think my issue is with the Navigation bar and custom logo image I added to the header. It seems that the logo is not resizing properly to allow everything else on the page to display properly on mobile. The Squarespace page can be found at https://richiequake.com and the password to view it is Help123.

**UPDATE**

I've been getting some progress. Using:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  #yui_3_17_2_1_1578763488616_571 {
    position: relative;
    right: 10%;
    width: 20%;
    top: -100%;
  }
}
```

I've been able to get the logo to move and resize, however the Nav bar that Squarespace automatically adds to the mobile view of the page is not properly placed, meaning I want the logo at the top of the page and the mobile nav bar underneath. This is my Navbar CSS when in mobile:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  #mobileMenuLink {
    position: relative;
    top: 20%;
  }
}
```

I can get to move the Nav bar and logo but for some reason it resets and displays as it was originally (logo too big and Navbar on top of the logo). How can I fix this and have these elements display properly on the mobile page?

Comment: This seems like as good a primer as any. You've got to invest a little time to learn about "media queries" and "responsive design". https://internetingishard.com/html-and-css/responsive-design/

Comment: Can you be more specific on what "does not display properly on mobile" means? Is the "mobile specific" css not working because you can't add it to SquareSpace or because the css isn't behaving how you expected? A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be better than a link to the site.

Comment: @sallf If I create a minimal reproduction of the site I have no issues, my problem is with how Squarespace sets up the pages and how I can control the CSS of these different elements. So after trying multiple media screen settings, I can't figure out how to implement the media CSS for Squarespace elements.

Comment: If you view the page on a mobile screen you can see what my issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
**"Square button":**

```
  .page-borders-thick #mobileMenuLink {
        border-bottom-width: 2px;
        padding: 5%; // ADD PADDING
    }
```

**"Position Of button":**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px)
#mobileMenuLink {
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block; //change block to inline
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #fff;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

**"Position and size Logo"**

```
.logo-image .logo img {
    position: relative;
    right: -50px;
    top: -100px;
    width: 100%; //add for good resize based to screen  
}
```

**Delete that code:**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px)
.canvas-style-masthead-logo-left.header-subtitle-none #lower-logo, .canvas-style-masthead-logo-right.header-subtitle-none #lower-logo {
     padding-top: 0px; 
}
```